# basic java if clause question

Tags: java, if-statement

this question is so basic that i don't even know how i could search for it...

now it's been a couple of years since i programmed but i did program for about seven years and i do distinctly remember (at least about C++) that whenever an if clause begins with e.g.:

```
if((x-1) >= 0) && ...
```

it simply does not matter what follows if the part left of the && is false. so how the hell could it be possible to get an array out of bounds exception for x = 0 when using "x-1" in the right part?

i never thought i would ever have to ask such a basic question... i hope i'm not overlooking something major (it is almost 4 a.m. ...) and hope somebody here can help...

Comment: The parentheses in your condition are wrong. Could you fix them to give better context?

Comment: If you can provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, I'm sure we can help you.

Comment: An empty array will throw an index out of bounds exception if you try to access element `0`.

Comment: You should be correct about the shortcut evaluation, so I'm guessing something else is amiss, but you didn't give enough of an example to tell for sure.  At any rate--it's bad form.  In 1/100 the time you spent figuring this out you could have created a nested if that is clearer in intent and easier to read.  It's criminal to waste your time AND the next persons by encrypting your code like that.  Welcome to Java.

Comment: If it is 4 am, you are not in a fit state to be writing / debugging programs.  Let alone venting your frustration on SO.  Go to bed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because (x-1) can be larger than 0 when x == array.length. The next condition is probably array[x], and array[ array.length ] -> OutOfBounds.

I assume you do something resembling:

```
if(((x-1) >= 0) && array[x] != null)
```

where you could have done something like:

```
int index = x-1;
if (index >=0 && index < array.length) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: first of all - i don't know what was going on there yesterday, i opened the project today, set a breakpoint in there to take a screenshot in debug mode so one could see the current value and the code around it but i never got an outofbounds exception any more.

it now works just like it should. and just for the record, here is what my code actually looks like - it is part of a recursive fill algorithm:

`if(x < 0 || x >= dimension || y < 0 || y >= dimension || board[x][y] == CHANGED) return;

board[x][y] = CHANGED;

/* cell left of current one */ 
if(((x-1) >= 0) && ...)

...`

Comment: also - thanks for trying to help, i really appreciate it! your comment definitely would've been the most helpful if what you described would have been the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

i assume the misplaced paranthesis are not in your code, because the compiler would complain otherwise.

it is also possible if x is not of type int but of some unsigned type. The only unsigned type that comes to my mind is char. So if x is a char and is 0, and you subtract 1, you end up with x being 65,535 and hence lager than 0